# kendo sortable with kendo observable array

Tags: kendo-ui

i am using kendo sortable data source is kendo observable array,
    when we sorting the divs we are updating the array object in change event,
    but array is updating properly but ui is not updating.
    can u please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="playlist">
            <ul id="sortable-basic" data-bind="source:items" data-template="template">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
            <li class="sortable">#:value#<span>#:time#</span></li>
        </script>
        <script>
            var data;
            $(document).ready(function () {

                data = kendo.observable({
                    items: new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
                        { value: 'Papercut', time: '3:12' },
                        { value: 'One Step Closer ', time: '4:10' },
                        { value: 'With You ', time: '5:00' },
                        { value: 'Points of Authority ', time: '2:59' }]
                        )
                });
                kendo.bind($('#playlist'), data);

                $("#sortable-basic").kendoSortable({
                    change: function (e) {
                        var daa = data.items.splice(e.oldIndex, 1);
                        data.items.splice(e.newIndex, 0, daa[0]);                        
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #example
            {
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            #playlist
            {
                margin: 30px auto;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #f3f5f7;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            }

            #playlist-title
            {
                height: 80px;
                border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            }

                #playlist-title span
                {
                    display: none;
                }

            #sortable-basic
            {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            li.sortable
            {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 6px 8px;
                margin: 0;
                color: #666;
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

                li.sortable:last-child
                {
                    border-bottom: 0;
                    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                }

                li.sortable span
                {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    color: #666;
                }

                li.sortable:hover
                {
                    background-color: #dceffd;
                }

            li.hint
            {
                display: block;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: #52aef7;
                color: #fff;
            }

                li.hint:after
                {
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
                    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
                    border-left: 6px solid #52aef7;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 216px;
                    top: 8px;
                }

                li.hint:last-child
                {
                    border-radius: 4px;
                }

                li.hint span
                {
                    color: #fff;
                }

            li.placeholder
            {
                background-color: #dceffd;
                color: #52aef7;
                text-align: right;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem. It seems to be the change function, just remove it and you can sort your list.

Comment: Hi Hinogi, u are correct ,if i removed change event it's working fine. but i want my observable array items also change based on the the divs sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used kendoSortable but I would assume that it is already maintaining the array sort because you have bound the array to the kendoSortable.  That's the purpose of binding, it keeps the data and elements in sync for you.  What you're doing in the change event is simply undoing the work that the binding just did, that is, sort the elements AND the bound array.

Answer (score 0):

As per telerik,
https://www.telerik.com/forums/sortable-and-moving-items-in-observable-arrays

You have to do this manually and attaching sortable to an array doesn't do anything automatically. So what you are doing is correct, however even though your changes reflect correctly in observable array it doesn't on screen.

So we have to trigger clear and change event, to sync UI with the array. There may be a better way invoke sync without having to clear out array but this was a hack that worked for me.

Here is a sample code where we clear the array and then re-insert which fixes the issue.

```
    $("#sortable-basic").kendoSortable({
                change: function (e) {
                    var daa = data.items.splice(e.oldIndex, 1);
                    data.items.splice(e.newIndex, 0, daa[0]);
                    var copiedArray = data.items.splice(0, data.items.length);
                    $.each(copiedArray,
                        function (index, item) {
                            data.items.push(item);
                        });

                }
            });
```